# Upload an image from input to server using JQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, amazon-s3

I have an Input like this:
`<input type="file" accept="image/*">`

Now I want to send the image to the server (I guess ajax is the way to go?)
From the Server I want to save the image to an aws-s3 storage (not actually my problem)
The question is how do I send the image to php in a way that I can later store it in an object storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code was copied from the following web page: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp**

*Note that it's much more harder to use AJAX/jQuery, so you can use this code.*

First check your php.ini file (it's in C:/php-install-path/php.ini) and search for the following line:

```
file_uploads = On
```

It may appear as

```
file_uploads = Off
```

so you need to turn in to `On`. Then restart your web server if it was off.

Next, create the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

It will need to redirect to a PHP file as PHP can receive  elements.

For the PHP file, put code like this:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

*Bonus: If you want to create a function for this, you can.*

```
<?php
function uploadFile($names, $button) {
  $file = $_FILES[$names];
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($file["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
  if(!empty($button)) {
    $check = getimagesize($file["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Check file size
  if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Allow certain file formats
  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
  if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($file["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $file["fileToUpload"] ["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Then include or require the file in the PHP file that's receiving the file upload.

```
<?php
include_once("file_upload_fn.php");
uploadFile("fileToUpload", $_POST['submit']);
?>
```

There you go. That's how you use PHP to upload an image.